# Android Studio gradle offline mode not found

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

Android Studio Preference to enable or disable **Offline mode** is not found in the latest Android Studio version 3.6.1.

[image]

From the build view suggestion, I was able to enable offline mode, but not able to disable now.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From the Android Studio 3.6 new features blog post:

New location to toggle Gradle's offline mode To enable or disable Gradle's offline mode, first select View > Tool Windows > Gradle from the menu bar. Then, near the top of the Gradle window, click Toggle Offline Mode Gradle offline button in the Gradle panel..

[image]

Comment: Hi, @Wahdat-Jan!  but I can't find gradle in tool windows menu bar. What's up?

Answer (score 3):

the setting for offline mode have changed again if you are on android studio 4.1 or above it has moved to the right side drawer of "gradle"

[image]